# Background color in tabsetPanel in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

How can I get a white background in `tabsetPanel`. For better understanding of my problem I'll bring up an example:

In my ui.R file I have the following:

```
mainPanel( wellPanel(wellPanel(plotOutput("densityPlot", height="500px"))), 
                               wellPanel(tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 

        tabPanel(h5("Text1"),p("Text" )),
        tabPanel(h5("Text2"), p("Text") ),                   
        tabPanel(h5("Text3"), p("Text"))),
        br(),
        br(),
        br()                           
    ))
```

To make it more clear please have a look at the picture below:
[image]

The difference is the white background area inside of any tagPanel. This combination of grey and white is the problem. Has anyone an idea, how can I get such a tagPanals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `style` option on the `wellPanel`:

```
runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100)
      ),
      mainPanel( wellPanel(wellPanel(plotOutput("densityPlot", height="500px"))), 
                 wellPanel(style = "background-color: #ffffff;", tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 

                                       tabPanel(h5("Text1"),p("Text" )),
                                       tabPanel(h5("Text2"), p("Text") ),                   
                                       tabPanel(h5("Text3"), p("Text"))),
                           br(),br(),br()                           
                 ))
    )
  )
  ,
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$densityPlot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
  }
))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it posible to control the background color for any tabPanal, for example the first one is white, second one is grey and the third one is lightblue? In this case they all have the same color. And it is prefered when one click on `Text1` so the other must be grey and not white, like in the picture I uploaded.

Comment: Any idea how one can achieve this style?

Comment: @And you should consider asking a separate question for this